# How does Type T = Type.GetType("SomeClass"); give me an object?

Tags: c#, class, object, types

When I am going through reflection I came across this:

```
Type T = Type.GetType("Somenamespace.someclass");
```

Is 'T' an object here? If so, it lacks the complete definition of object as:

```
Type T = new Type();
```

Then how can `T` be an object? And how can we assign the value of `Type.GetType("Somenamespace.someclass");` into `T`?

Comment: If you're new to C#, you may not want to dive into reflection right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, T is an object of class `Type`, which:

> Represents type declarations: class types, interface types, array
>   types, value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type
>   definitions, and open or closed constructed generic types.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Type.GetType("Somenamespace.someclass");
```

is a static method of Type class, which will return the `Type` object with properties and methods that are relevant to this particular class. It will not be an instacne of `Somenamespace.someclass`.

Comment: Dude what about this.......
              `try {}
              catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }` 
Does here also   `exception e ` simply creating object here?......Does the above given explanation works for this also?

Answer (score 3):

`T` is an object of [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx). It is not an instance of `someclass`, if that was what you wanted to know.

The `Type`-class is used to describe class-declarations and some more.

To address your comment:

```
Type T = new Type();
```

can only be called by other Constructors of `Type` as well as classes that inherit from `Type`, as the [parameterless `Type`-Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.type(v=vs.110).aspx) is declared `protected`, and it would not make sense to call it in normal code (what would it describe?). A typical call woud be sth. like that:

```
var obj = new someclass();
var type = obj.GetType();
```

Comment: @ nozzleman yeah I got that.....but how by writing just Type T creates object to class Type as it lacks full definition as Type T = new Type();

Comment: @METALHEAD somewhere in `Type.GetType()` there's also a `new` statement (or something that comes down to the equivalent of instantiating an object). You don't need to see `new` in _your_ code to get an object assigned to a variable.

Comment: Dude what about this....... `try {} catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); }`Does here also `exception e` simply creating object here?......Does the above given explanation works for this also?

Comment: well, that is another question, but the short answer is no: the `Exception e` part simply defines what exceptions should be catched by the block it is defined on top of. The Exceptions is instanciated within the `try`-block (one method or a method called by a method and so on does that and throws it, which makes it accessible in the catch block.) Think of throw like calling a a catch-method. catch is basically like a nested method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. such this:

```
var someclassType = Type.GetType(“Somenamespace.someclass”);
var someclassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(someclassType);
```

And another example :

```
using System;

class DynamicInstanceList
{
    private static string instanceSpec = "System.EventArgs;System.Random;" +
        "System.Exception;System.Object;System.Version";

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] instances = instanceSpec.Split(';');
        Array instlist = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), instances.Length);
        object item;
        for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++)
        {
            // create the object from the specification string
            Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of: {0}", instances[i]);
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(instances[i]));
            instlist.SetValue(item, i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nObjects and their default values:\n");
        foreach (object o in instlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type:     {0}\nValue:    {1}\nHashCode: {2}\n",
                o.GetType().FullName, o.ToString(), o.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}

// This program will display output similar to the following: 
// 
// Creating instance of: System.EventArgs 
// Creating instance of: System.Random 
// Creating instance of: System.Exception 
// Creating instance of: System.Object 
// Creating instance of: System.Version 
// 
// Objects and their default values: 
// 
// Type:     System.EventArgs 
// Value:    System.EventArgs 
// HashCode: 46104728 
// 
// Type:     System.Random 
// Value:    System.Random 
// HashCode: 12289376 
// 
// Type:     System.Exception 
// Value:    System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown. 
// HashCode: 55530882 
// 
// Type:     System.Object 
// Value:    System.Object 
// HashCode: 30015890 
// 
// Type:     System.Version 
// Value:    0.0 
// HashCode: 1048575
```